# How to draw the following picture using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw the following figure in LaTeX using tikz (if possible)?

[image]

How to draw the figure with the fruits replaced by letters or numbers?

Comment: Show us what you've tried already. This isn't a "please draw this for me for free" website.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: I don't how to proceed. I tried to do mimic the apple in Geogebra but it failed.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough:...and by the way, isn't [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176239/how-to-draw-this-picture-with-latex-tikz) also a "draw this for me" type question in disguise?

Comment: There are plenty of questions like this, and they have been the subject of several debates on Meta: ["Draw this for me" etiquette](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4591) [How do I draw this.....?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6125) [Our Do-it-for-me and Draw-it-for-me comments don't reflect our hypocrisy. Can they be improved?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4267) [Consistent policy about downvoting and asking the OP to 'show what they have tried'](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2879)

Comment: Long story short: Not everyone likes this sort of question, but often they get answers anyway, as some people just like the challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!  The `matrix of nodes` from the `matrix` library seems to be ideal for that task.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=1em] (m)
  {
    $S$: & apple  & apple  & apple  & apple  & apple  \\
    $T$: & 1      & 2      & 3      & 4      & 5      \\
    $W$: & banana & banana & banana & banana & banana \\
  };
  \foreach \y in {1,3} {
    \foreach \x in {2,...,6} {
      \draw[<->] (m-\y-\x) -- (m-2-\x);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Is it impossible to retain the original form of the picture?

Comment: @user170039 What do you mean by that? The arrow tips, the font, the fruit images?  If you'd like to keep the original layout *exactly*, I'd suggest `\includegraphics{original-image}`.