# Random lines in a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, plot

[image: type of plots I have to deal with]

Hi everyone, I have never used pstricks or tikz and it seems to be the best option to draw the kind of plots that I need.

I have been researching and I have not found how to draw this random line which represents the inventory level, using coordinates does not seem an option to draw that line.

Does anyone know what command or package should I use? 
I would really appreciate if someone could answer a similar code for this plot, so I would have a basis to start drawing these stuff

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that what you are looking for is TikZ with PGFPlots. You need to create and upload a complete working example, before you ask about the concrete problem. http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/

Comment: You might use one of the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160237/draw-somewhat-random-function) as a starting point.

Comment: And welcome to TexSE, by the way!

Comment: To make your random walk lines, you might also find [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59926/how-to-draw-brownian-motions-in-tikz-pgf) useful.