# Temperature/atmosphere graphics

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I would like to draw the following image but I can't imagine how to handle it (packages? Tikz?).

[image]

I'd really appreciate your precious help.

Comment: Do you have the data/equation for the line? The `pgfplots` package is a good choice.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the data/equation but I think it is the following one: [link] https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/3/4/a/34a0ac7f5271087b101d4e14b877bbd4.png [\link]

Comment: You can find a basic `pgfplots` example in [Best way to generate a nice function plots in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3622) (first answer). Work out the equation and try using that. If you can't make it work, edit your question to include the code you have so far.

Comment: When you don't know the exact equation you can use the various techniques demonstrated in the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160237/draw-somewhat-random-function) about drawing a "random" function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version in PGFplots, produced by changing the labels and the equation from the linked answer, and adding some options.  I guessed at a suitable equation.  I don't really know anything about PGFplots, but I'd quite like to learn more, so I looked things up in the [the manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf).  I must admit that I find the manual a bit overwhelming, but it does have some simpler introductory parts at the beginning.  This whole exercise took me about 20 mins; I'll leave any further customizations "as an exercise for the reader".

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
          width=5in, height=3in,
          domain=0.1768:2.828,
          xtick={0.0,0.5,...,3.0},
          ymin=50,ymax=130,
          ytick={50,60,...,130},
          grid=both, no markers, smooth
          xlabel={$P$ Atmospheres},
          ylabel={$T$ ${}^\circ$C}
      ]  
  \addplot {100 + 20/ln(2)*ln(x)}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]