# Diagram with curves and semi solid lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

Any advice for the following figure will be highly appreciable. [image]

Comment: semisolid meaning *dashed*?

Comment: Yes. Semisolid means dashed.

Comment: Advice: try to find a similar picture, have a go, then ask question when you get stuck.   Maybe this one:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160237/draw-somewhat-random-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,latex-] (0,6) -- (0,0) node[midway,sloped,below]{RR};
\draw[thick,latex-] (6,6) -- (6,0) node[midway,sloped,above]{EE};
\draw[dashed,thick,-latex] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[midway,above]{KK};
\draw[dashed,thick,-latex] (6,-0.2) -- (0,-0.2) node[midway,below]{CC};
\draw[name path=plot1,thick,blue!50] plot[variable=\x,domain=0.2:5.8] 
({5.8*(1-pow(cos(\x*15),2/3))+0.2},{5.8*pow(sin(\x*15),2/3)-0.4});
\draw[name path=plot2,thick,purple] plot[variable=\x,domain=0.2:5.8] 
({5.8*pow(cos(\x*15),2/3)-0.2},{5.8*pow(sin(\x*15),2/3)-0.4});
\draw[dashed,thick,name intersections={of={plot1} and {plot2}}]
($(intersection-1)+(0,1)$) -- ($(intersection-1)-(0,1)$)
($(intersection-1)+(1,0)$) -- ($(intersection-1)-(1,0)$);
\draw[thick,blue!50] (1.5,6.5) coordinate(left) -- (2,6.5) node[right,black]{xx};
\draw[thick,purple] (3,6.5) -- (3.5,6.5) node[right,black](yy){yy};
\node[draw,fit=(left) (yy)]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]