# Plotting an illustration of the learning rate in neural network learning using TikZ package

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I know how to plot an arbitrary curve using the `smooth` interpolation, but what I want is to add annotations similar to the ones in the image below in order to illustrate how the learning rate works.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160237/15036

Comment: Is this what you want `\node at (1,2) {$t=1$}`? You need to show your code for the graph and describe what is causing you problems.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.